What is the correct way of using server functions in client side code in Next.js 14
I am loading data from database on a server from all users and need to display it on a site as a list (something like <li>{email}, {id}</li>).
I want to use fetch as a GET method that returns my data as JSON, but I cannot really use that because main function is not async so I cannot do something like
const res = await fetch(...)
const data = res.json();

because of await.
I also cannot make main function async since I have useState() and "use client".
There is an option of using useEffect() but apparently that is bad and should be avoided.
So what would be the correct way of doing it?

Importing Server Components into Client Components is not a supported pattern.
A typical pattern is to pass the Server Component as a prop to a Client Component.
"use client";

import { useState } from "react";

export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Type your name"
      />
      {children}
    </>
  );
}


An alternative way to use a data fetching library such as SWR and fetch data in the Client Component itself.
"use client";

import useSWR from "swr";

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const { data } = useSWR("/api/data"); // Make sure the API route is authenticated

  return <div>{data}</div>;
}



You can extract that part of your component which you want to be server-side into another file and use SSR there.
client side
"use client"
import React from 'react'

const ClientSide = () => {
  //states and Effects
  return (
    <div>
        <ServerSideComponent/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ClientSide

server-side
const ServerSideComponent = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("/");
    const data = await res.json();

    return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
};

export default ServerSideComponent;



Although this does work, I am bombarded with "async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components" warning. Is this really the correct way of doing it? Or did I do something wrong?

did you extract the code into another file ?

Yes, I extracted it in another file. Should it be placed in some special place or is something missing?
